# Unknown error while building application

Tags: iphone

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_Assert", referenced from:
      -[GoogleDocs verifyAccountUsername:password:] in GoogleDocs.o
      -[GoogleDocs beginUploadData:withTitle:inFolder:replaceExisting:] in GoogleDocs.o
      -[GoogleDocs beginDownloadTitle:inFolder:] in GoogleDocs.o
      -[GoogleDocs beginFileRetitleFrom:toTitle:inFolder:] in GoogleDocs.o
      -[GoogleDocs beginFileDeleteTitle:inFolder:keepingNewest:] in GoogleDocs.o
      -[GoogleDocs beginFolderCheck:createIfNeeded:] in GoogleDocs.o
      -[GoogleDocs docListListFetchTicket:finishedWithFeed:] in GoogleDocs.o
      ...
     (maybe you meant: _AssertSelectorNilOrImplementedWithArguments)
  "_DebugLog", referenced from:
      -[GoogleDocs fetchDocListForFeed:title:username:password:] in GoogleDocs.o
      -[GoogleDocs docListListFetchTicket:finishedWithFeed:] in GoogleDocs.o
      -[GoogleDocs inputStream:hasDeliveredByteCount:ofTotalByteCount:] in GoogleDocs.o
      -[GoogleDocs uploadFileTicket:finishedWithEntry:] in GoogleDocs.o
      -[GoogleDocs uploadFileTicket:failedWithError:] in GoogleDocs.o
      -[GoogleDocs downloadEntry:] in GoogleDocs.o
      -[GoogleDocs retitleNextFile] in GoogleDocs.o
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I got a sample project for uploading and downloading the text to google doc from iphone sdk,the sample projects works fine,but i integrate this project to my application i got the above error.I have added all the frameworks into it,but no luck.I added all the classes to my project.Any one have any idea about this error please help me.
Regards Nipin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you are importing a **header file**, that does not exist in your app.
There is a Symbol your app can not find.